# How to navigate from master detail page to content page in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, master-detail

I have a login page which is a navigation page and here i navigate to master detail page .but now i want to go back to login page when i click on logout button.here is what i do for this.
[My login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtQSS.png) and [Master detail page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNADV.png) i want ,when i click on logout,the control exist from MDP and go back to Login page.

My LoginVM

```cs
//here i navigate to my home page(Master detail page)

if (user.UserName == Employees.UserName && user.Password == Employees.Password)
{
    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("success", "Login success", "OK");

    await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
    var masterDetailPage = new MasterDetailPage1();
    masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
    Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
}
```

My master detail page Xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyProject.Views.Profile.MasterDetailPage1"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views.Profile"
                  >
    <MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Logout" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"/>
    </MasterDetailPage.ToolbarItems>
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>

        <pages:MasterDetailPage1Master x:Name="MasterPage" />

    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>

  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>

</MasterDetailPage>
```

CS of master deail page

```cs
public partial class MasterDetailPage1 : MasterDetailPage
{           
    public MasterDetailPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();               
    }

    //some other code

    private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (this.Detail as NavigationPage).PushAsync(new LoginPage());
        //App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());
    }
}
```

but i does not work .it navigate to login page successfully but in toolbar it display logout and back button which i don't want. so how i do this

Comment: What is your requirement? If you want to know about Navigation in MasterDetailPage you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page.

Comment: Thanks for answering but i need something different in simple world i want to exist from master detail page after clicking on logout button.i want to go back on same login page which appears first when my app runs first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                var masterDetailPage = new MasterDetailPage1();
                masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
                Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetailPage;
```

Here you declare your mainpage's detail as a navigation page, and set it as your current mainpage. But you are in your NagiationPage now, so when you call

```
            (this.Detail as NavigationPage).PushAsync(new LoginPage());
```

You push a new LoginPage in your navigation stack, but your other page is still accessible via back button, what you want to do is to redefine your mainpage :

```
                Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
```

Comment: thanks for helping .this really helpful.please tell me one more thing.As you can see in login page it navigate back to an  other page.but when i logout it calls a new login page which does not navigate back to page.Is it possible to go back to that page which is call by first login page from current login page. i hop you understand my point.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to call the following line of code in your LoginVM. Because at the end you are setting `Application.Current.MainPage`.

```
await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Why do you want to push the login page? If you want to log out the user completely, he/she should not be able to return to the previous page by clicking the back button.

In my opinion, you should set the `Application.Current.MainPage` again. Probably the same as you did in your `App.xaml.cs`.